# __set_name__ execution in Descriptor

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I have came across a code that it is including descriptors. As I understand, `__set_name__` is a method that is called when the class is created. Then, if the class is called twice I'd get two calls.

In the following snippet I would expect to get the call in `__set_name__` twice, but I am getting just one call. Why this behavior?

```
class SharedAttribute:
    def __init__(self, initial_value=None):
        self.value = initial_value
        self._name = None
    
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        if self.value is None:
            raise AttributeError(f'{self._name} was never set')
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, new_value):
        self.value = new_value

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        print(f'{self} was named {name} by {owner}')
        self._name = name


class GitFetcher:
    current_tag = SharedAttribute()
    current_branch = SharedAttribute()

    def __init__(self, tag, branch=None):
        self.current_tag = tag
        self.current_branch = branch
    
    @property
    def current_tag(self):
        if self._current_tag is None:
            raise AttributeError("tag was never set")
        return self._current_tag

    @current_tag.setter
    def current_tag(self, new_tag):
        self.__class__._current_tag = new_tag

    def pull(self):
        print(f"pulling from {self.current_tag}")
        return self.current_tag


f1 = GitFetcher(0.1)
f2 = GitFetcher(0.2)
f1.current_tag = 0.3
f2.pull()
f1.pull()
```

During the previous execution, `__set_name__` is called with current_branch, but not called with current_tag. Why this distinction? The only call is this one:

```
<__main__.SharedAttribute object at 0x047BACB0> was named current_branch by <class '__main__.GitFetcher'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR By the time `__set_name__` methods are called, `current_tag` refers to an instance of `property`, not an instance of `SharedAttribute`.

---

`__set_name__` is called *after* the class has been defined (so that the class can be passed as the `owner` argument), not immediately after the assignment is made.

However, you changed the value of `current_tag` to be a `property`, so the name is no longer bound to a `SharedAttribute` instance once the class definition has completed.'

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) (emphasis mine):

> Automatically called at the time **the owning class owner is created**.

The `SharedAttribute` instance is created while the body of the `class` statement is being executed. The class itself is not created until *after* the body is executed; the result of executing the body is a namespace which is passed as an argument to the metaclass that creates the class. During that process, the class attributes are scanned for values with a `__set_name__` method, and only *then* is the method called.

Here's a simpler example:

```
class GitFetcher:
    current_branch = SharedAttribute()
    current_tag = SharedAttribute()
    current_tag = 3
```

By the time `GitFetcher` is defined, `current_tag` is no longer bound to a descriptor, so no attempt to call `current_tag.__set_name__` is made.

It's not clear if you want to somehow compose a property with a `SharedAttribute`, or if this is just an inadvertent re-use of the name `current_tag`.

Comment: Maybe for the OP it also helps to know that properties are implemented as descriptors, so essentially for `current_tag` the `SharedAttribute` descriptor is replaced by the property descriptor.

Comment: It's not really relevant; the point is, `current_tag` is *not* a `SharedAttribute` anymore, regardless of what it has become. (`property.__set_name__` isn't defined anyway.)

Comment: I think it's not obvious to many that decorating a method with `property` overwrites the attribute.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you decorate it with `property` or not. The `def` statement itself redefines the attribute.

Comment: ah, true, I had overlooked that.

Comment: Why if I change the order of assignation and have current_tag = ShareAttribute() first and then current_branch = ShareAttribute() is happening the same. What is the difference between current_tag and current_branch? Both of them are class attributes. I edited the order in the question.

Comment: They are both class attributes, and so is the property you are defining. It has nothing to do with the order in which `current_tag` and `current_branch` are defined relative to each other. You are *redefining* `current_tag` before any descriptor's `__set_name__` method is called. The original `ShareAttribute` object is discarded once you define the property with the same name.